# Android Sliding Drawer slow in changing fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

I am trying to use the sliding drawer to change the Main page's fragment.
What is happening is, I see the drawer closes and than half - 1 second and than the fragment starts changing.

I think this behavior is too slow and from the other Apps, I still during the drawer closes, the fragment has already changed and it looks much better.

Any idea on how this can be accomplished??

Comment: There's not much that can be said without looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your at with the application, you may want to take a look at androids navigation drawer. There is a straight forward tutorial here. https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Also, if your using android studio, you can create a new project and specify a navigation drawer for the navigation and it will autocreate one for you.

If your having speed issues when switching fragments, you will want to provide the code here so we can review it. Also, take a look to see if your doing any resource intensive calls when creating the fragment. That could slow down the process some.